# Graphs defined by chords of a circle

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

Drawing chords between some points on the periphery on a circle disc defines [simple graphs](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html) where the chords are the vertices and crossing of two chords in the *inner* of the disc defines the edges. Obviously all circuit graphs, complete graphs and complete multipartite graphs can be represented in this way and my question is if every simple graph can?

Comment: Do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_graph ? It is a reasonably well studied, nontrivial graph class

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek - Yes, thanks! I didn't know it's name. So there are counter examples of graphs that are not circle graphs?

Comment: The https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_graph $W_5$ might be the first easy counterexample. https://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_132.html

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek - Why don't make an answer?

Comment: You may have seen [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82178643.pdf) where the characterization of circle graphs is given.